# Is it normal to be able to put signs on each other? (Minecraft)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As of Beta 1.5_01, is it normal to be able to put signs on each other? Not in your inventory, but in the actual world, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is possible.

[image: Stacked signs(physically)]

**EDIT:**

I tried putting a sign in front of each other, but the end result is not of that in your picture. However, you can use world-editing tools (such as [WorldEdit](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit)) to do make the signs in that way.
[image]

Comment: You can also do this to the front of the sign.

Comment: And you can attach sings to the edges of other signs (The Mobavator is based on that)

Comment: how about in front of each other, like in my picture?

Comment: And that looks like an older version of Minecraft. It might be different.

Comment: @user9090 i have edited my answer.